# Gas Range 20 amp Circuit Breaker

Tags: gas, range

I have a gas range. 120v, 16 Gauge 15 amp Plug. Can I use the 20 amp Ciruit Breaker that is currently in the house?

Comment: Are you saying you have a 20A circuit available for the range or are you trying replace a 15A breaker with a 20A breaker?

Comment: What sort of receptacle is on the circuit you are trying to plug the range into?

Comment: The way the question is worded is concerning because you specify a 120v 15A 16 AWG plug. That is some very precise information which is leading into a "wait, what are you doing" question.... IF AND ONLY IF the Gas Range is a 15A rated appliance can you use a 15A plug on it. Are you replacing the plug on the stove? If the plug is the plug that came WITH the stove, and all you are asking is if you can plug it into a 20A circuit, using an existing 20A outlet, YES you can. I wouldn't think a GAS range would consume 15A, so I wouldn't expect your stove to be 20A (unless its got an element).

Comment: You mean the appliance cord is 16 AWG, not the wiring in the walls...

Answer (score 1):

Standard appliance cordage is usually 16 AWG and yes you can plug this device (stove) into a 120v 20 amp circuit. Toasters and hair dryers are usually larger because of the load but your range is listed for use on a 15 or 20 amp circuit.

Comment: Unless it has an electric element (dual heat source) or some other fancy options. I just wasn't sure if she was clear that it is a basic stove. It sounds like it. Its just interesting that she read the AWG of the cord.... But did she read the stoves cord or is she replacing the end "for some reason" (it jsut wasnt clear)

Comment: Yes. I have a 20amp ch avail. Can I use this breaker with the 15 amp plug on the gas range

Comment: The answer is yes you can use a 15 amp device or cord on a 20 amp circuit. The difference in cord connected devices is that is the only load where outlets can have many things plugged in so the wire size is required to be larger to keep from overloading the wire and the heat that is generated from breaking down the insulation. So a device that comes with a 15 amp cord and plug can be used on a 20 amp circuit.